# Error logging is truncated in Laravel of Guzzle http

Tags: laravel, guzzle

Guzzle http is truncating exceptions with more than 120 characters, but I need to log the full exception message. How can I do this?

I am using laravel 4.2.22.

Answer (score 27):

```
try {
    // whatever
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $ex) {
     return $ex->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents(); 
     // you can even json_decode the response like json_decode($ex->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents(), true)    
}
```

Answer (score 11):

It is the same for Laravel 5 and 4

```
    try {
        $response = $client->post($path, $params);
    } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException $ex) {
        \Log::debug('error');
        \Log::debug((string) $ex->getResponse()->getBody());
        throw $ex;
    }
```

if you just go to `$ex->getMessage()`, you will get
`(truncated...)`
at the end.

Comment: Can you please explain, what would "auto-complete correctly" and how can "the methods above fail"?

Comment: Thank you. You are right, this code would create unexpected exception depressing. I've changed the code.

Answer (score 3):

Might be better solution:

```
try {
    // do request here like:
    // return $client->post($path, $params);
} catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ServerException $ex) {
    $exFactoryWithFullBody = new class('', $ex->getRequest()) extends \GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException {
        public static function getResponseBodySummary(ResponseInterface $response)
        {
            return $response->getBody()->getContents();
        }
    };

    throw $exFactoryWithFullBody->create($ex->getRequest(), $ex->getResponse());
}
```