# Mailchim api works but not as php script

Tags: php, laravel, mailchimp

If I execute this in terminal:

```
curl -X POST https://<ds>.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/<list_id>/members?skip_merge_validation=true --user "anystring:<APP_KEY>" -d '{"email_address":"testemail@example.com","email_type":"text","status":"subscribed","merge_fields":{},"interests":{},"language":"","vip":false,"location":{"latitude":0,"longitude":0},"marketing_permissions":[],"ip_signup":"","timestamp_signup":"","ip_opt":"","timestamp_opt":"","tags":[]}'
```

User is successfully added. But when I try in my laravel app, like the mailchimp documentations says [here](https://mailchimp.com/developer/marketing/api/list-members/add-member-to-list/), I got an error Bad Request 400 and can't actually see it because laravel truncates it in the error log. My laravel code looks like this:

```
$mailchimp = new \MailchimpMarketing\ApiClient();

    $mailchimp->setConfig([
        'apiKey' => APP_KEY',
        'server' => SERVER
    ]);
    

        $response = $mailchimp->lists->addListMember('88b0ab829e', [
            "email_address" => "example@example.com",
            "email_type" => 'text',
            "status" => "pending"
        ]);
        print_r($response);
```

Comment: Your CURL and PHP Clients call looks different.  is the body is really same?

Comment: Think so, the other fields can be empty as I understood their documentation

Comment: Probably using guzzle as request library, so check here to get the full exception message - https://stackoverflow.com/q/53862823/1427878

Comment: Is that your actual code?  I'm assuming `APP_KEY` is a constant but in this case there seems to be an extra `'` at the end. Not sure if that's a typo in your question or possibly the cause of your issue.